# perl breaks file path into new lines

Tags: perl

Instead of printing the file into one line, the output is a bunch of new lines. What am I ding wrong in the file path of this perl script? 
Script:

```
my $app = $ARGV[0];
my $day=`date -v-1d '+%d'`;
my $month=`date -v-1d '+%b'`;
my $yr=`date -v-1d '+%Y'`;
my $file = "/path/to/file/$app/$yr/$month/treshold-$day .log";
print $file;
```

Result:

```
$ perl test.pl inter
/path/to/file/inter/2013
/Dec
/treshold-13
```

Output should be: /path/to/file/inter/2013/Dec/treshold-13.log

Comment: You're probably running into the `\n` at the end of each of the `date` statements; try `chomp $day;` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`date(1)` write an end-of-line at the end of the output. Use `chomp` to throw it away.